# Problem relating to dividing persons in a group

Tags: probability

The question states as follows

> There are only two women among 20 persons taking part in trip. The 20 persons are divided into 2 groups each consisting of 10 persons . Than the probability that two women will be in the same group is :

My method

- Total ways = $(20!)/(10!×10!×2!)$ means by dividing them in 2 groups of 10 .
- Favourable ways = $(18!)/(10!×8!)$ bydividing 18 persons in 2 groups of one 8 and other 10 persons .

So as to send 2 women with group of 8 persons dividing these I get $9/19$ as the answer. But given answer is $9/38$ . Can someone tell what I have missed and what is the correct approach
 Thanks

Comment: I think you are correct because when you find probability of them going to different groups is (remember you have to arrange women in 2 groups formed )= $\frac{{18 \choose 9}2!}{{20 \choose 10}}$ is $\frac{10}{19}$

Comment: Suppose there were $2N$ people in total. Then we would expect the probability to tend to 0.5  as $N\to\infty$. So the given answer looks implausible.

Comment: Book gives answer as $18C8/20C10$=$9/38$

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.

Suppose everyone picks up a ticket giving their group from one of 20 face down on the table. One woman is the first to pick up a ticket. The chance that tne other picks up a matching ticket is $$\frac{9}{19}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct but somehow begs for a more simple approach.

---

Let's call the women Alice and Beatrice.

By the formation of groups Alice will be joined by $9$ of the other $19$ persons.

What is the probability that Beatrice is among these $9$ persons?

This already "smells" very much as $\frac9{19}$, but let us formalize a bit.

You can think of this as $9$ choices that are to be made out of $19$ persons.

For *every* $i\in\{1,\dots,9\}$ all $19$ persons *have equal chances* to be chosen at the $i$-th choice.

So if $B_i$ denotes the event that Beatrice is chosen at the $i$-th choice then:$$\{\text{Beatrice will join Alice}\}=\bigcup_{i=1}^9B_i$$and consequently:$$P(\text{Beatrice will join Alice})=P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^9B_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^9P\left(B_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^9\frac1{19}=\frac9{19}$$